# como subir una imagen a un servidor remoto

Tags: php

Buenas Tengo este problema estoy trabajando en un servidor remoto y quiero subir una imagen en una carpeta que yo cree en el servidor remoto como foto estoy utilizando este código pero no me funciona sera que alguien me podría ayudar gracias de antemano:

codigo:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "XXXXXXX";
$username = "XXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXX";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection

$nom=$_REQUEST["txtnom"];

$carpeta_destino = "foto/";
opendir($carpeta_destino);
$destino = $carpeta_destino.$_FILES['foto']['name'];  
copy ($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],$destino);
echo "Archivo subido exitosamente";
$nombre=$_FILES['foto']['name'];
echo "<img src = 'foto/$nombre'>";



$insertar = "INSERT INTO foto (nombre,foto)VALUES('$nom','$destino')";
$resultado =  mysqli_query ($conn,$insertar);

if (!$resultado){
    echo 'Error al registrarse ';
}else{
   header("Location:index.php");
} 
?>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir a la pregunta el código HTML de la cabecera del formulario que utilizas para enviar el archivo?

Comment: gracias: <form action="validar_foto.php" method="POST" enctype ="multipart/from-data">
<center><table border="1"></center>
<tr>
 <th>Nombre:</th>
 <td><input type="text"id="txtnom"name="txtnom"values=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <th>Foto:</th>
 <td><input type="file"id = "foto"name="foto"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"> <input type ="submit" name="enviar" values="enviar"></td>
</tr>

Comment: No olvides modificar la pregunta para que incluya el código que incluyes en el comentario :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Lee con detalle lo que sigue:

Realicé algunas observaciones al código que has escrito y encontré que lo puedes solucionar de la siguiente manera:

- Reemplazar `enctype=multipart/from-data` por `enctype=multipart/form-data`.
- Que el directorio `foto` necesita permisos para poder continuar con la subida de los archivos. En este caso, si el propietario del directorio no es `apache`, sino, tu usuario, entonces cámbialo escribiendo: `chmod 777 foto`. Esto es solo mientras estés desarrollando, aunque no se recomienda tener los permisos a `777`. En su lugar, se puede escribir: `sudo chown www-data.www-data foto` para establecer a `Apache` como propietario del directorio `foto` y establecerle los permisos a `0755`, es decir, `sudo chmod 0755 foto` para permitir que los archivos se copien.
- `opendir($carpeta_destino);` no se ha destinado para subir los archivos. Su propósito es leer el directorio para obtener un listado de archivos. Puedes ampliar en: [PHP: opendir - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.opendir.php.)

### A tomar en cuenta:

- Mientras trabajes con Windows no habrá necesidad de preocuparse mucho por el tema de los permisos. Solo tienes que reemplazar `enctype=multipart/from-data` por `enctype=multipart/form-data`.
- También, puedes escribir `php -S localhost:8080` para montar un servidor Web con PHP sin necesidad de utilizar `apache` con independencia del sistema operativo utilizado. Lo único que tienes que realizar, en este caso, si no utilizas Windows es establecer los permisos descritos anteriormente en esta respuesta.

Comment: Sabía que el problema tenía que estar en el HTML, la de veces que se me habrá olvidado el `enctype`... Buena vista con el from :)

Comment: Gracias David :)